# Wireshark 2.2.2 missing Debug Console option

Tags: console, wireshark

I'm using Wireshark version 2.2.2 on Windows 7.
When I go to `Edit -> Preferences...` there is nothing about Debug Console window.
I know there should be a combobox to let me choose "Always" or "Never". it's not there.
I think this option is missing in Wireshark 2.0.5 as well.

How can I display/hide the console window?

Answer (score 0):

The preference has been moved.  You can now find it via *Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced*, then scroll down until you find, or more simply just search for, **gui.console_open**.  Change the value from **AUTOMATIC** to either **NEVER** or **ALWAYS** by the value drop-down.  You will need to restart Wireshark for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! can't understand why did they kicked it off the main preferences screen.

Comment: I suppose it was removed from the main preferences page because it's probably not a preference that most people use or care about, so it reduces some clutter for most people. Removing it also presents a more uniform view of preferences across platforms.